# Is it true Deck$(H \backslash \widetilde {X},X) \cong \frac {N(H)}{H}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

> Let $\widetilde {X}$ be the universal cover of a 'nice' space $X$. Suppose $H$ be a subgroup of Deck $(\widetilde {X},X)$.Is it true that Deck$(H \backslash \widetilde {X},X) \cong \frac {N(H)}{H}$ where $N(H)$ denote the normalizer of $H$ in Deck $(\widetilde {X},X)$?

I think its not true but unable to comp up with example.Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's true: let $p: \tilde{X}/H \to X$ be the covering map. Then you have $\text{Deck}(\tilde{X}/H, X)\cong N(p_\ast \pi_1(\tilde{X}/H))/p_\ast \pi_1(\tilde{X}/H)$ and $p_\ast \pi_1(\tilde{X}/H)\cong \pi_1(\tilde{X}/H)\cong H$ since $\tilde{X}$ is simply connected.